# Going back to previous location after following link (org-open-at-point)?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Is there an Emacs function to go back to previous location after I follow an Org link? I usually use bc-set from the breadcrumb.el package, but I'd prefer something builtin from org-mode.

Comment: AFAICS `org-open-at-point`'s default behavior is opening the link in a new buffer, isn't it (at least my local installation does this).  Shouldn't you be able to "go back" by just killing the buffer (`C-x k`) or switching buffers (`C-x b`)?

Comment: It doesn't open a new buffer if the link is an internal link (link to the same file).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are following an internal link (i.e. a link to a target in the org-mode file), then org-mode automatically pushes the position in the mark-ring before jumping.

So, you follow a link with `C-c C-o`, then you can jump back with `C-c &`.

Documentation [here](http://orgmode.org/manual/Handling-links.html#Handling-links).

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted. The default key binding is a tiny bit cumbersome though :)